# Getting back null results from mybatis query using resultMap

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to combine my Oracle SQL queries to populate my POJO's into one mybatis call. I want to get back from my DAO a list of ParentClass objects, each of which contains a ChildClass object as an element along with a String key.

Currently my SQL query works in Toad as expected, meaning it returns all of the data for each parentKey in a row for an expected amount of parentKeys. When I move over to my Spring web service however I am getting back no data at all from my mybatis query, but no errors. I have used mybatis before by have never used resultMap before so my question is if I am implementing this correctly and if not, what needs to be added/modified?

ParentClass.java

```
public class ParentClass {
    private String parentKey;
    private ChildClass childClass;
}
```

ChildClass.java

```
public class ChildClass {
    private String childElementA;
    private String childElementB;
}
```

myMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
   PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
   "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="myMapper">
    <resultMap id="parentClassResultMap" type="myPackage.ParentClass">
        <result property="parentKey" column="PARENT_KEY" />
        <association property="childClass" resultMap="childClassResultMap" />
    </resultMap>
    <resultMap id ="childClassResultMap" type="myPackage.ChildClass">
        <result property="childElementA" column="CHILD_ELEMENT_A" />
        <result property="childElementB" column="CHILD_ELEMENT_B" />
    </resultMap>
    <select id="getData" parameterType="String" resultMap="parentClassResultMap">
        SELECT PARENT_KEY, 
            MY_TABLE.CHILD_ELEMENT_A AS CHILD_ELEMENT_A,        
            MY_TABLE.CHILD_ELEMENT_B AS CHILD_ELEMENT_B
        FROM MY_TABLE
        WHERE MY_TABLE.PARENT_KEY IN (SELECT MY_TABLE.PARENT_KEY
                                        FROM MY_TABLE
                                        WHERE MY_TABLE.PARENT_KEY LIKE #{ key })
    </select>
</mapper>
```

MyDao.java

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {
    @Autowired
    SqlSession sqlSession;

    public List<ParentClass> getData(String key) {
        return sqlSession.selectList("myMapper.getData", key);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you print the spring web executed sql? I think you need check your key parameter when using `like`

Comment: Turns out you were right. I had forgotten to append a necessary wildcard character to my key at the DAO level, so everything was working correctly. Thanks for bringing this point up.